# How to install Bioinformatics libraries like trimmomatic, bowtie2, samtools, seqtk etc. in AWS linux OS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-18.04, bioinformatics, amazon-linux-2, samtools

I am not able to find a way to install Bioinformatics and other supported packages in AWS linux based OS while these works in ubuntu and their documentation says they support linux based OS. Is there any command to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/index.html) to install many common bioinformatics packages. For example: use `conda install seqtk` or `conda create --name seqtk seqtk` to install the `seqtk` package.

Comment: May I recomend explaining the need for channels for conda as well as  short discussion for this user on momba.  The user may find this useful when they go to find packages in conda forge.  Also probably best to supply them a link to conda forge.

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-ggplot2

Comment: If otehr read this, abscially you need to set the channels on your conda forge for certain things.  Google "how to set conda channels" and add the one for R.  You will then be abel to copy paste the instillation lines from conda forge and check if a package you need for R is maintained on conda.

Answer (score 0):

This `docker` [container](https://github.com/bcgsc/orca) has most of the bioinformatics software you'll ever need. You can get the image and work in the running container.
If you're not comfortable working with Docker containers yet you can go to each software's own website and download it according to their suggestions.